# Check the status of an uploaded video takes 30 minutes

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We use the YouTube Data API to upload videos, but when we check the status of the uploaded video with 1 minute period, it will take more than 15-30 times until the status change to success.

Our video size is less than 5M.

what can we do to make it faster?

Comment: here is the api:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-upload-check-status

Comment: This is not an issue of YouTube Data API, but one of YouTube's back-end. I'd suggest to address this issue on the appropriate [Google's support forum](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3545535?hl=en). They have all the info they need to know why takes it so long to process such short videos.

Comment: When a video is uploaded whether using the API or the web browser, it takes some time after the video is uploaded before the YouTube back-end finishes processing the video. The time varies depending on the size of the video and how busy the back-end is processing other videos. There is nothing you can do to make it faster.

Comment: It's not normal to wait 30 minute unitl the video status change to success while our video is short and small.  It maybe stuck somewhere, and we want to known what can we do to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

We found that the tagSuggestionsAvailability and editorSuggestionsAvailability is always "inProgress" while the processingDetails.processingStatus maybe "succeeded" or "processing".

We also found that if the processingDetails.processingProgress.partsProcessed is 1000 and processingDetails.processingProgress.timeLeftMs is 0 while the processingDetails.processingStatus is "processing", maybe the video is succeeded.

So while the processingDetails.processingStatus is "processing", if the availablility is all "available" except tagSuggestionsAvailability and editorSuggestionsAvailability, or processingDetails.processingProgress.partsProcessed is 1000 and processingDetails.processingProgress.timeLeftMs is 0, we think the video is successed.

It works for me, sometimes maybe fail, but we just need one minute to wait the video status change. Does anyone have better ideas for this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).